# How can I set page style for just a whole section or chapter?

Tags: bibliographies, pagestyle

So what I am trying to achieve is to set the page style as, say, `plain` for a current whole section ONLY, and then let the page style return to whatever it used to be after this current section.

Also, it would be wonderful if the setting can recognize by itself the end of current section.

For example, I would like to set the page style to be `plain` for `\bibliography` and let it return to whatever it was in `\appendix`.

Comment: Try `{\pagestyle{plain}\bibliographystyle{yourStyle}
\bibliography{yourFile}}`. I mean enclose the `\pagestyle` command inside curly brackets together with your `\bibliography` command.

Comment: Sure. Use `\clearpage \pagestyle{plain} <your bibliography> \clearpage \pagestyle{<original>}`. Is this what you're after?

Comment: @Werner This worked and thank you for providing that approach. Also, is there a way where I do not need to recognize the end of reference?

Comment: IIRC, pagestyle uses global macros and will not reset at the end of a group.  "It is supposed to automatic, but you actually have to push this button."